# Click event in Fragment for MVVMCROSS

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a fragment class, like this one:

```
public class TMSAccountFragment : MvxFragment
{
    //some code
}
```

Button click event:

```
#region OnClick of account button

ImageView acc_Button = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.accountbutton_orange);
acc_Button.Click += delegate
{
    OnClick();
};

#endregion

public void OnClick()
{
    FragmentTransaction ft;
    Fragment frag;

    frag = new TMSSlidingTabsFragment();
    ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    ft.Replace(Resource.Id.sample_content_fragment, frag);
    ft.AddToBackStack(null);
    ft.Commit();
}
```

The following error happens in `FragmentManager.BeingTransaction();`.

> cannot implicitly convert type `'android.support.v4.App.FragmentTransaction' to 'Android.App.FragmentTransaction'`

Answer (score 0):

use getSupportFragmentManager() instead getFragmentManager().you should change your onclick like as below

```
public void OnClick()
 {
 Fragment frag = null;
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();   
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =   fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 frag = new TMSSlidingTabsFragment();
 fragmentTransaction .Replace(Resource.Id.sample_content_fragment, frag);         
 fragmentTransaction .AddToBackStack(null);
 fragmentTransaction .Commit();
 }
```

Comment: nope dude, there is problem in getSupportFragmentManager(); error is getSupportFragmentManager(); does not exits in current context

Comment: did you use PagerAdapter?

Comment: Yes I have use PagerAdapter, but in different fragment

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SupportFragmentManager` instead of the regular `FragmentManager`.

```
public void OnClick()
{
    var fragment = new TMSSlidingTabsFragment();
    var transaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.sample_content_fragment, frag);
    transaction.AddToBackStack(null);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

However, since you're using MVVMCross, I **strongly** advise you to use the MVVM Pattern. That is, bind this `Click` event to an `IMvxCommand` in your VM and use a proper presenter to handle the way your Fragments will be presented (some useful resources to get started can be found [here](http://slodge.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/n26-fragments-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html) and [here](http://gregshackles.com/presenters-in-mvvmcross-navigating-android-with-fragments/))